# buddypress is_page not working

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Wordpress Version 4.8.1
Buddypress version 2.9.0

************** EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT **************

THIS IS A VERY SIMPLE REQUEST. I honestly don't understand why no one seems to be able to answer such a basic request, i've been googling this for weeks now. I'll try and explain again, pls bear with me:

In buddypress,

1. I WANT to know if I'm on page "X".
2. IF I AM, then do an action or add some styling

THAT'S IT! really, that is it.

In previous version of Buddypress, the function is_page used to work for ALL pages. For instance this example still works:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
    <style>.homepage i {color:#ffd647 !important;}</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But in the current version of BP, once I go into a forum page, it no longer works, like in this example:

```
if ( is_page( 'forums' )) : ?>
    <style>.homepage i {color:#ffd647 !important;}</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I'm guessing is_page has been deprecated (a stupid decision if that's the case).

Can anyone help me with this problem? Please!!! The BP documentation is very poor. Thanks

************** End of EDIT **************

Comment: If your site is online, can you please share the URL? Or if it's on local, add the page source here. Include the above code and then visit `/forums` page, provide source code of that page.

Comment: Hi, just added the source to header.php of the theme I'm using. Let me know if that helps

Comment: You got me wrong. I meant the page source code that the browser renders. In Chrome, right  click and `View Page Source`. Include that

Comment: THIS IS A VERY SIMPLE REQUEST. I honestly don't understand why no one seems to be able to answer such a basic request. I'll and explain again, bear with me:

Comment: You did not share URL or source code (browser HTML source) and unfortunately, we can't imagine your code.

Comment: You seem obsessed with viewing my code for such a basic request. Anyway, if anyone's interested, I got it working:

<?php if (bbp_is_single_forum() || bbp_is_single_topic() || bbp_is_single_reply() || bbp_is_topic_edit() || bbp_is_topic_merge() || bbp_is_topic_split() || bbp_is_reply_edit() || bbp_is_reply_move() || bbp_is_single_view()) {
    ?>
        ... your code here ...
 
<?php } ?>

In this example, if the user is in a forum page, you can run whatever code (like changing a css style, or echoing something)